# corLocal in R for Pearson or kendall correlation P and slope

Tags: r, correlation, raster

I am trying to run corLocal on 2 stacks (average temperatures, day of the year for spring- over a 17 year period. I.e. 17 tiff files for temp and 17 tiff files for day of the year). I've used the following line

```
p <- corLocal(stack1, stack2, method = "kendall") ##or pearson
```

I would like to get the p value and sens slope value as 2 separate rasters but I am not sure what my output is - it ranges between -0.5 and 0.5. Thank you,

```
p <- corLocal(stack1, stack2, method = "Kendall")
```

p-value and slope value 2 separate rasters files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
s <- r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=17)
values(r) <- runif(size(r))
values(s) <- runif(size(s))
sr <- sds(r,s)
```

To get the Kendall correlation coefficient for each cell (across the 17 layers).

```
ken <- lapp(sr, \(x,y) {
        out <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
        for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
            out[i] <- cor(x[i,], y[i,], "kendall", use="complete.obs")
        }
        out
    })
```

And to get the p-value

```
pken <- lapp(sr, \(x,y) {
        out <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
        for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
            out[i] <- cor(x[i,], y[i,], "kendall", use="complete.obs")
            out[i] <- cor.test(x[i,], y[i,], method="kendall", use="complete.obs")$p.value)
        }
        out
    })
```

For completeness: the `corLocal` method (called `focalPairs` in "terra") can be usd to compute the focal correlation between layers.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
set.seed(0)
r[[1]] <- flip(r[[1]], "horizontal")
r[[2]] <- flip(r[[2]], "vertical") + init(rast(r,1), runif)
r[[3]] <- init(rast(r,1), runif)
```

Kendall correlation coefficient and p-value

```
x <- focalPairs(r, w=5, \(x, y) cor(x, y, "kendall", use="complete.obs"))
y <- focalPairs(r, w=5, \(x, y) cor.test(x, y, method="kendall", use="complete.obs")$p.value)
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert but I'm not sure I understand. I want to see if temperature is correlated to the day of the year (DOY) of a particular event. I have 17 TIFF files for temperature (for 17 years) and 17 TIFF files for DOY I stacked the 17 temperature files (stack(temp)); and 17 DOY files (stack(DOY)). I tried
x <- focalPairs(r, w=5, (x,y) cor(stack(temp),stack(DOY), "Pearson", use="complete.obs")) But got the error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘focalPairs’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer"

Comment: That states that you cannot use  `focalPairs` with a ‘"RasterLayer" (from the "raster" package). It needs to be a "SpatRaster" (from the "terra" packages). See `?focalPairs`